# Google Maps API - delay marker creation in for loop

Tags: javascript, html, flask

I saw a very old thread on this but the solution doesn't work. I am trying to create an array of google maps markers, and display them on a map from within a for loop, but I want a delay between each marker being shown (and they would be displayed by either refreshing the page or ajax, but I can try to add ajax after this part works). Everything works but the delay, all the markers are shown immediately. New to web development, so I know there's probably something fundamental I am missing here. My javascript code is below, any help would be much appreciated. Thank you. I am working in Flask (python) although I don't think it matters much.

```
function initMap() {

    var options = {
        zoom: 5,
        center: {lat: 32.7767, lng: 96.7970}
    }


    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);


    var markers = [
        {
            coords: {lat: 29.4241, lng: 98.4936},
            content: '<h1>San Antonio</h1>'
        },
        {
            coords: {lat: 32.7767, lng: 96.7970},
            content: '<h1>Dallas</h1>'
        },
        {
            coords: {lat: 29.7604, lng: 95.3698},
            content: '<h1>Houston</h1>'
        }
    ];


    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            alert("Hello");
        }, 3000);
        addMarker(markers[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can multiply your timeout by `i` so that you have 3000ms, 6000ms, 9000ms etc and then set the timeout in a function that is called from within the loop.

Something like

```
function addMarker(marker, delay) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(marker); // do whatever your addMarker stuff does here.  the setTimeout needs to be within this function.
    }, delay);
}

var markers = ["hello", "goodbye", "hola", "adios"];
for(var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    addMarker(markers[i], 3000*i);
}

// hello, goodbye, hola, adios
```

Notice that I'm passing the delay in to `addMarker` as the 2nd parameter.  You'll need to change your addMarker method to allow that (or do a composite function if this isnt a method you can change).

If that's necessary, it'll look something like:

```
function myAddMarker(marker, delay) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        addMarker(marker);
    }, delay);
}

var markers = ["hello", "goodbye", "hola", "adios"];
for(var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    myAddMarker(markers[i], 3000*i); // call the **my**AddMarker method here instead of the regular one
}

// hello, goodbye, hola, adios
```

I had originally had this, which looks functionally identical but because JavaScript is funny, it will execute the last one 4x (which will be undefined, because `i` will go out of bounds after the last iteration)

```
var markers = ["hello", "goodbye", "hola", "adios"];
for(var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(marker[i]);
    }, 3000*i);
}
// undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined
```

You can see better what I mean if you don't let `i` go out of bounds, by subtracting 1 from the max:

```
var markers = ["hello", "goodbye", "hola", "adios"];
for(var i = 0; i < markers.length-1; i++) { // notice the -1 here
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(marker[i]);
    }, 3000*i);
}
// adios, adios, adios, adios
```

The last thing you'll probably want to do is address the delays.  I'm doing `3000 * i`, so on the 0th iteration it happens immediately (3000 * 0 = 0ms delay).  That's just a math tweak though.  You might want to do `3000 * (i + 1)` to get it to go at 3000, 6000, 9000 etc or maybe `3000 + (i * 200)` to get it to go at 3000, 3200, 3400, etc.

**Aside on why the weird identical-but-different behavior:**

The anonymous function within the `setTimeout(...)` gets created after the delay occurs.  The entirety of the `for(...)` loop already ran by that point, so `i` is equal to `markers.length`.  Since arrays are 0-based, `markers.length` is actually beyond the last element in the array.  The last element in the array is `markers.length - 1`.

To avoid this problem, you can do something like I did above (calling a function, and that function creates the timeout) or you can pass a named function to the `setTimeout(...)` so that the function is **not** anonymous, thus **not** created after the delay.

```
function doSomething() {
    ...
}

var markers = ["hello", "goodbye", "hola", "adios"];
for(var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(doSomething, 3000 * i);
}
```

...but now you get in to having a function which takes no parameters, so you have to return a function from a function (or bind a scope to it) and it gets ugly fast.  It's easiest to just cram the `setTimeout(...)` into the function like in the first code block.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. If I try your code as is, no markers get placed. If you don't mind giving it a try when you get a chance, I would much appreciate it. No problem if not. Will keep trying in the meantime. Thank you.

Comment: @hitachi7 i got the chance to try it.  I was right about it repeating the last thing N times.  I've updated the answer with something that'll work.

Comment: man thank you so much for this, and for the explanation on what's going on, will help me a ton on javascript going forward